# php email - $to multiple recipients

Tags: php

Even this must have been be asked many times, I will ask again since I cannot get it to work.

I am using php `mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: $mysite<$myemail>\nX-Mailer:PHP/" .phpversion());` to send email to a single recipient.

Now I need to sent it to more than one recipients. I know that normaly I could do:

```
$to = "emailA@here.com,emailB@there.com";
```

But I need the one of the recipients to be the user that fills in the form e.g.:

```
//get all form details
$email = $_POST['email'];

$to = "$email,emailB@there.com";
```

The above ($to) I don't know if it is correct or not but is not working for me...

If I leave only the `$to = "$email";` it gets send to $email **(meaning that my rest of the code is ok)**.

Any suggestion on what is or may be wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you have when you `var_dump($to);`

Comment: echo "|$to|" after you assign it and see what it says (post it here).

Comment: try an explicit concatenation like $to = $email.'emailB@there.com'; does that make a difference?

Comment: try putting `{}`'s around `$email`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a CC to your header.

```
$header ="From: $mysite<$myemail>" . PHP_EOL;
$header .= 'CC: emailB@there.com' . PHP_EOL;
//Rest of headers here
```

Comment: Plain and simple... Thank you :)